# 301 Redirects from pages that have query string to static pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to do a bunch of redirects in the following format:

```
site.com/page/page.aspx?id=1234
to site.com/page/page
```

I was trying to use the following:
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1234
RewriteRule ^page/page.aspx http://example.com/page/page/final-page [R=301,L]

Right now I get back the following site.com/?1234 that isn't what I want... I want to get the new url site.com/page/page/final-page

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1234 
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ http://example.com/page/page/final-page?  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The same thing happened... it redirected back to the homepage with just the ?id=1234 appended. Not sure why adding the ? isn't working

Comment: Do you have the directive "AllowOverride all" in your vhost or apache.conf file?